# OnActivityResult activity error : Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, retrofit2

> error : Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100,
>   result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:28362
>   flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {com.projectbox.uploadfile/com.projectbox.uploadfile.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPo

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        android.net.Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        File file = new File(filePath);

        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("banner", file.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "banner");

        Log.d("THIS", data.getData().getPath());

        retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = service.postImage(body, name);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("FFF", t.getMessage());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error stack:

```
Process: com.projectbox.uploadfile, PID: 17822
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:28362 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.projectbox.uploadfile/com.projectbox.uploadfile.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4220)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4263)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262)
at com.projectbox.uploadfile.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:110)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7025)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4263) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
```

Comment: Can you add the code, where you fire the Intent to request the image?

Comment: @AbhishekS Hope My Answer will solve your problem

Comment: Do you want to create new image always? You are getting null in  `data.getData();`

Comment: A NPE . Can you point out the exact line where you getting Npe . is `filePath` returning null?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the filepath is null. You are trying use the mediastore `DATA` column to get a File from a `content://` URI. This may or may not work as explained by Mark Murphy in [How to Consume Content From a Uri](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

The only reliable way to get the content is to use [`ContentResolver.openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri))

You can then either copy the stream to a file before uploading it or directly upload the stream as explained by this [OkHttp recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#post-streaming).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **wrong image path or Relative Image Path** here. I Think that must Be the problem..

### Try Replacing

```
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
```

### With

```
Cursor cursor = null;
Uri contentUri = data.getData();
String filepath = "";
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

Hope this will Solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling keep activities from developer options ...that may be one of the cause I have faced earlier

Answer (score 0):

`if(!cursor.moveToFirst())` or `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath))` you should return from method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        android.net.Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return;

        if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.close();
            return;
         }   
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath))
          return;

        File file = new File(filePath);

        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("banner", file.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "banner");

        Log.d("THIS", data.getData().getPath());

        retrofit2.Call<okhttp3.ResponseBody> req = service.postImage(body, name);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("FFF", t.getMessage());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```